# IOS If device has no internet connection how to detect it and show an according text

Tags: ios, swift, connectivity

I am trying to build a simple app, that actually wraps a webpage, but I would like to not open an webview and show a message when device has no connection. I found an URLSessionConfiguration, but i have no idea how to implement it, help much appreciated

Code so far

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {


        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let url = URL(string: "https://neti.ee")
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        config.waitsForConnectivity = true
        config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 300
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        session.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
        }
        myWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url!));
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 220, height: 50))
        label.text = "Please connect to the internet";
        self.view.addSubview(label)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a method that listens to changes in the internet connectivity state and gets triggered whenever the internet becomes disabled, you can use the `NWPathMonitor` class from the `Network` framework introduced in iOS 12. The `pathUpdateHandler` closure of `NWPathMonitor` is called whenever there is a change in the network path, including changes in internet connectivity state.

Here's how you can use `NWPathMonitor` to achieve this:

```
import UIKit
import Network

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
var internetIsAvailable = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Start monitoring network path updates
    monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
        self.internetIsAvailable = path.status == .satisfied
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.handleInternetConnectivityChange()
        }
    }

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "NetworkMonitor")
    monitor.start(queue: queue)
}

func handleInternetConnectivityChange() {
    if internetIsAvailable {
        print("Internet is enabled")
        // Internet is enabled, you can perform actions here
    } else {
        print("Internet is disabled")
        // Internet is disabled, you can perform actions here
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method and `import SystemConfiguration`

```
static func isInternetAvailable() -> Bool
{
    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
    
    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
        }
    }
    
    var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
        return false
    }
    let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
    let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)
    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it with this file imported into your project:
[Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/blob/master/Sources/Reachability.swift)

And then, in your viewController you can check the connection like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let reachability = try! Reachability()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        reachability.whenReachable = { _  in
            //connected
        }
        reachability.whenUnreachable = { _ in
            //not connected
        }
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(internetChanged), name: Notification.Name.reachabilityChanged , object: reachability)
        do{
            try reachability.startNotifier()
        } catch {
            print("Could not strat notifier")
        }
    }
    
    @objc
    func internetChanged(note: Notification) {
        //do something
    }
}
```